# How to display dots in place of long text in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

- I have a table view with 2 rows.
- in these rows in **detail TextLabel** i have long text i didn't want to display all the text but
- I need to display dots for last characters if it is a long text
- *for ex:*
- text in cell.**detailTextLabel** is :**'DATABASE Entered in to the cell'**
- I want like as : **'DATA BASE Ente.......'**

How it is possible?

Comment: All of the answers should work for you. How are you trying to set the lineBreakMode? How are you creating your label?

Comment: Thank u very much sir. Problem solved .Thanks for ur quick response. dot will come automatically. - Problem is in width of the table view exceeds 320

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dot will come automatically.

if your text is big compre to label size. then dot will come automatically.

ya you have to fix size of font.

Comment: please explain your question in detail.

Comment: Thank u very much sir. Problem solved .Thanks for ur quick response. dot will come automatically. - Problem is in width of the table view exceeds 320

Answer (score 2):

use label to display and set the property like

```
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
```

Comment: Thank u very much sir. Problem solved .Thanks for ur quick response. dot will come automatically. - Problem is in width of the table view exceeds 320

Answer (score 1):

You can set the property of `UILabel`:

```
@property(nonatomic) UILineBreakMode lineBreakMode
```

Comment: Thank u very much sir. Problem solved .Thanks for ur quick response. dot will come automatically. - Problem is in width of the table view exceeds 320

Answer (score 1):

Set lineBreakMode of UILabel to UILineBreakModeTailTruncation, but it's the default value already. :-)

Comment: Thank u very much sir. Problem solved .Thanks for ur quick response. dot will come automatically. - Problem is in width of the table view exceeds 320

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `adjustFontSizeToFitWidth` to `NO` and set `lineBreakMode` to `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation`

Comment: Thank u very much sir. Problem solved .Thanks for ur quick response. dot will come automatically. - Problem is in width of the table view exceeds 320